# ECC Random Points Generation FPGA

Tags: java, c#, random, fpga, elliptic-curve

I want to give a large number of ECC points to my FPGA for testing purpose. I want to save the file containing ECC points as well. Is there any way , I can generate ECC random points for specific Elliptic curve? May be directly in FPGA or I can generate it using any other tool (using any other programming language) and then use them there. Any recommendations??

Comment: Please define ECC.

Comment: @Paebbels Elliptic Curve(s) Crypto, I would venture

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux My intention was to trigger a question edit. So the question defines often overloaded abbreviations. (`ECC = {Error Correcting Code(s), Error Checking and Correction, Elliptic Curve Cryptography, ... European Coaster Club}` :) ). A question should be readable without googling abbreviations...

Comment: @Paebbels Would the entities of operating with an error correcting code be "points"? I've only heard points used when ECC stood for elliptic curve cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so, assuming that you already have a generator point and the ability to perform [scalar*point multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) (by doing point addition in the correct succession). Use an LFSR or other means of generating a random scalar up to the order of the group and multiply the generator point by that scalar.

Comment: What if I get the file (containing random ECC points) generated using bouncy castle Java  and then read file in FPGA code and do rest of my stuff?  As in my case, I need random points, it doesn't matter if that is done in FPGA or not! Implementing it in FPGA might be complex and time consuming!! I am new to FPGA but i believe file handling will be straight and easy as is in C and java?

Comment: @user2982318 I don't see the point then. What are you going to do with those points if you don't have point addition and scalar multiplication implemented?

Comment: I have already done that part. Implemented ECC on FPGA (for single hard coded input point) now I want to test it for huge random ECC points on physical board.